# (R) I am trying to remove all days with rain from my dataset, along with the day after

Tags: r, dataframe

I thought about making some sort of counter column that resets to 0 every time there is precip. Then, I could filter out all rows with a 0 or 1 for the counter. But I cannot quite get the syntax to work...

I am using R, and have dplyr and tidyverse installed.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimum reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a stab,

```r
precip <- c(F,T,F,F,F,T,F,F,T,F)
precip
#  [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
ave(precip, cumsum(precip), FUN = function(z) seq_along(z) - z[1])
#  [1] 1 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 0 1
```

The `- z[1]` is a special case for when the first element in `precip` is false (as it is here).

Comment: Great, this worked, thank you! May I ask what z represents?

Comment: It's an arbitrary name for the single argument to an anonymous function. That is, I could have done `function(x) seq_along(x)` or `function(tmp_variable_name) seq_along(tmp_variable_name)` and it would have been the same thing in effect. I do consider it *slightly sloppy* to use single-letter variable names, but in quick single-line anon-funcs like this, I think it is acceptable.